# Linphone PushKit - Not receive VoIP PushKit in TestFlight mode

Tags: ios, voip, linphone, pushkit, linphone-sdk

I'm working on linphone iOS repository and I made some UI changes and added some new features to it for customization! Now, I wanna add VoIP PushKit capability to this project for receive incoming calls when app is in background mode or force closed by user!
I created all necessary certificates for it from the apple developer account and everything is ok in development mode ( when run the app in my iPhone by usb cable ) but when I build the app for production mode and send it to AppStore connect and release it to TestFlight, The app can not receive pushes from APNS! PushKit Token is registered and I save it in my server db successfully but when I send a VoIP push to app, is not received! I try to get log of installed app ( TestFlight mode ) and I've found out push receive to OS but the OS not awake the app and delivered the push to my app!
Please help me to fix this problem! TNX all!

Answer (score 0):

If in your development environment, everything is working (meaning: you get the PushKit notification and also the corresponding SIP INVITE and CallKit is launched and you can take the call), it probably means that you haven't switched your APNS client from development to production. See e.g. under https://github.com/nomad/houston :

```
# conveniently use `Houston::Client.development` or `Houston::Client.production`. 
APN = Houston::Client.development
APN.certificate = File.read('/path/to/apple_push_notification.pem')
```

Comment: Hi guy! Thanks for your suggestion but we switched the APN Service from development to Production for sending pushkit voip notify

Comment: @AliZareSharAbadi did you find any solution ?